# What does it mean when a ghost has appeared in a galaxy in Super Mario Galaxy 2?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

Sometimes after getting a star in *Super Mario Galaxy 2* for the Nintendo Wii, often after playing as Luigi, I will get a message similar to:

> A `ghost` has appeared in the `some galaxy name` galaxy!

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens whenever you play through a level as Luigi.

It means you've unlocked the developer time trial ghost -- a translucent Luigi near the start of the level that races to the end when you get near it.

You don't get anything for beating the ghost, however.

Comment: It doesn't always race to the end, sometimes, it gives you hints for alternate routes.

Comment: Actually, it *always* runs to either an alternate route or hidden item.

Comment: Thanks @Powerlord! Now I'm definitely going to go back and look for it! Is there any indication on the map when a ghost has appeared?

Comment: There is *some* indication when you roll over the level on the map screen, though I can't remember what exactly.

Comment: Sometimes the hidden items aren't that useful.  As I recall, it runs to a 1-up in Boulder Bowl Galaxy.  Although that does show you how to get the Comet Medal if you didn't already have it.

Answer (score -3):

It is a Nintendo staff time for you to race against. It appears if you beat the level as Luigi. It will appear on all levels if you get 9999 coins.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?  Everything I find doesn't have this as a requirement, so I'm inclined to disbelieve it.